# html height for a percentage doesn't seem to work

Tags: html, css, height

I expected <div style="height:50%;background-color:cyan;" to draw a blue box on the screen. But it doesn't. Only the area I fill with characters becomes blue.
So how I do draw a colored box of say 33% of the visible height of the parent?
I seem to remember it actually working at some time, but I cannot remember how it was done.
Poul

````
<html>
<style>
.worksOK {
  background-color: cyan;
}
.DoesntWork {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
</style>
<body>
<h1>Height % doesn't seem to work</h1>
<div class = "worksOK" style="height:75px;">
  A fixed height, like <b>height:50px;</b> works fine
</div>
<div class = "DoesntWork" style="height:75%;">
  But a height in percentage, like <b>height:50%;</b> doesn't seem to work.
</div>
<br>It does however work in this demo:<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playdemo.php?filename=playcss_height">w3schools</a><br><br>Unfortunately I cannot access the css code, so I do not understand why that is.<br>
And I cannot recall ever have been able to make height work with a percentage.

</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: 50% *of what*? Unless the container has a height, how will it know how to calculate 50%

Comment: 50% is just half of whatever it is. I very much expect DOM to be aware of the height of any and all elements placed on the screen, so it should be 0,5 times present height. Since it used to wprk, something along those lines must have been in effect. I think it is pretty nice to implement something like vh. What I find absolutely weird is that they change the previous usage. That must have been giving

Answer (score 0):

add a height for the container, for example, here I am adding 100vh  (the viewport height) to the body

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
.perc50 {
  height: 50%;
  background: aliceblue;
}
.a {
  background: teal;
}
.b {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="perc50"> content</div>
<div class="perc50 a"> content</div>
<div class="perc50 b"> content</div>
</body>
```